# Query to get 3 variations of City Name

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders
WHERE date_ord >=  '2015-02-16'
AND date_ord <=  '2015-02-26'
AND active =1
AND (
(
ship_city =  'NYC'
OR ship_city =  'New York'
OR ship_city =  'New York City'
)
AND ship_state =  'NY'
)
OR (
(
bill_city =  'NYC'
OR bill_city =  'New York'
OR bill_city =  'New York City'
)
AND ship_state =  ''
)
ORDER BY ordId
```

Customers have added "New York" city name in 3 variations like "NYC", "New York" and "New York City". I need to query all those records where billing city is all 3 variations and shipping state is empty or NULL and those records where shipping city is new york using all 3 variations of city name and shipping state is set to 'NY'. In short, all orders which are shipped to New York City. (Billing state can be CA or FL)

This query is not perfect. I am getting records older than date range. Please suggest fix for this.

As suggested by @Ash and @DovesandChicks i tried to do it using IN function

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders
WHERE date_ord >=  '2015-02-16'
AND date_ord <=  '2015-02-26'
AND active =1
AND ship_city
IN ('NYC',  'New York',  'New York City')
OR (bill_city IN ('NYC',  'New York',  'New York City') AND ship_state =  'Unlisted')
ORDER BY ordId
```

Still something wrong with query. Please help

Comment: This is why you should have cityid instead of city names in your orders table. (And constraints in your tables, to avoid such mess...)

Comment: You have redundant brackets. Also, I suggest you replace your multiple 'OR' s in ship_city with an 'IN' clause. You are also just querying for records with "date_ord =  '2015-02-16'", so no need for the >= and <=.

Comment: See my comments below, the problem is you have an OR clause that doesn't have brackets around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can use
AND ship_city IN ('NYC', 'New York', 'New York City')
2) You don't have enough brackets round your OR clauses. You need to have all the ORs in one bracket

so

WHERE (date bit)
AND (city bit with ORs)

I can write it all out if you need me to:

```
    SELECT * FROM tblorders 
WHERE dateord >= '2015-02-16' 
AND dateord <= '2015-02-26' 
AND activeFlag =1 
AND (s_city IN ( 'NYC', 'New York', 'New York City' ) OR ( b_city IN ( 'NYC', 'New York', 'New York City' ) AND s_state = 'Unlisted' )) 
ORDER BY ordId
```

Comment: ok I tried to simplify according to your and @Ash suggestion using IN
and query is like this now
    SELECT * 
FROM tblorders
WHERE dateord >=  '2015-02-16'
AND dateord <=  '2015-02-26'
AND activeFlag =1
AND s_city
IN (
'NYC',  'New York',  'New York City'
)
OR (
b_city
IN (
'NYC',  'New York',  'New York City'
)
AND s_state =  'Unlisted'
)
ORDER BY ordId

Comment: You still have an OR that is spoiling your query. Make sure you have brackets round all the OR options otherwise you end up with Select correct date OR correct city

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have unnecessary brackets near OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders
WHERE date_ord >=  '2015-02-16'
AND date_ord <=  '2015-02-26'
AND active =1
AND (
        (
            ship_city =  'NYC'
            OR ship_city =  'New York'
            OR ship_city =  'New York City'
        )
        AND ship_state =  'NY'

    --)
        OR 
    --(

        (
            bill_city =  'NYC'
            OR bill_city =  'New York'
            OR bill_city =  'New York City'
        )
        AND ship_state =  ''
    )
ORDER BY ordId
```

with proper formatting the query is more readable

condition can simplified in this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders
WHERE date_ord >=  '2015-02-16'
AND date_ord <=  '2015-02-26'
AND active =1
AND ship_city in  ('NYC','New York','New York City')
AND ship_state in ('NY','')
ORDER BY ordId
```